# Git Clone Local Repo with all Branches but no commit history to another local repo

Tags: bash, git, github

I have two local repos on my computer: A & B. I need to copy A to B, so that all branches are copied, but only the latest 5 commits history.

When copying, I need any branch named `master` to be renamed to `main`. Each branch then needs reconnected with the remote so that I can publish the branches to Github.com.

I have attempted to write a bash script to handle this, but the problem is that the branches lose the connection to the remote and cannot be published.

**Github for Desktop Error:**

> Unable to push commits to this branch because there are commits not he remote that are not present on your local branch. Fetch these new commits before pushing in order to reconcile them with your local commits.

My .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

repo_name=TestRepo
dir=/Users/username/development/$repo_name
repo_src_url=git@github.com:my_username/$repo_name.git
repo_target_url=git@github.com:my_username/$repo_name.git

git clone --no-single-branch --depth 5 $repo_src_url $dir \
  && cd $dir \
  && git branch -m master main \
  && git commit --amend --author "John Smith <john@johnsmith.com>" -m "Initial Commit" \
  && git branch --unset-upstream \
  && git remote set-url origin $repo_target_url
```

Comment: Totally unclear. What would multiple branches but no history even mean? You just want a collection of unrelated commits floating in a kind of virtual limbo?

Comment: @matt all branches of repo should be included, but either no commit history or at the very least the latest commit.

Comment: You may find it easier to 1) create an empty repo 2) check out a branch in the old repo 3) create same branch in the new repo 4) copy all files to the empty repo 5) add and commit them … repeat for all branches, ensuring to create main first and branches off main. There are existing questions with some more detailed answers (e.g. search for “squash all history”) but ultimately what you are asking for is sufficiently unusual to be unique afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this up top here, but per your comments below, you've started out with the wrong question (even after updating it).  What you want is described as follows:

- There is some existing repository (and/or clones of it but we care about a particular repo on GitHub).  It has *N<sub>1</sub> > 1* branch names in it, selecting *N<sub>2</sub> > 1* tip commits.  One of these branch names is or may be `master`.
- We'd like to clone this repository and create, locally, all *N<sub>1</sub>* branch names, selecting all *N<sub>2</sub> commits*, while changing the name `master` to `main`.
- Then we'd like to rewrite all the commits so that each branch has a history whose depth is no more than 5 commits, but all the *tip* commits retain any relative relationship they had before.
- We will then push this to GitHub, into a currently-empty repository.
- It's not clear what, if anything, we wish to do with all the *tag* names.

(Then we want to repeat this for more repositories.)

There is in fact no fully general solution to this problem as stated because it may require more than 5 or so commits on each branch, depending on relationships.  For a trivial example, consider the following graph:

```
A   <-- br1
 \
  B   <-- br2
   \
    C   <-- br3
     \
      D   <-- br4
       \
        E   <-- br5
         \
          F   <-- master
```

Here, to keep the relationships between commits intact, we must in fact copy *all six commits* (and hence there's no history rewriting involved in the end, in this example; we would just change the name `master` to `main` and be done with things).  Each of the six commits *is* a tip commit on a branch: `A`, the root commit of the repository, is the tip commit of `br1`, `B` is the tip of `br2`, and so on through `F`, which is the tip of `master`.  But the final depth of `main` (renamed from `master`) will be 6, not 5.

Fortunately, the "depth no more than 5 commits" constraint appears to be very weak here: we'd just like to perhaps retain a few *extra* commits in some cases.  For instance, given this repository:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- br1
                   \
                    H--I--J--K--L--M--N   <-- master
```

we might produce, as our revised history:

```
C'-D'-E'-F'-G'  <-- br1
             \
              J'-K'-L'-M'-N'  <-- main
```

That is, we've shrunken the depth of `br1` to 5, and retained just five *extra* commits on `main`: commit `C'` is the effect of squashing `A-B-C` together, and `J'` is the effect of squashing `H-I-J` together.

This *is* solveable.  However, there's no tool *included with Git itself* that solves this problem.  What we'll need is a program like `git filter-repo` (this will be easier to use, probably) or `git filter-branch`; we will need to write code.  How much code and how complex it gets is up to you, but here's the basic task:

- enumerate each *labeled* commit, so that we know which commits *must* be retained;
- traverse the entire graph: for each labeled commit, retain it and (optionally) some depth of previous unlabeled commits, up to whatever limit you like.
- Retain (as a new root) any commit required to keep branch relationships intact, even if it would not be retained by the previous rules.

(Note: for the "enumerate labeled commits" step, `git for-each-ref` does the job.  To handle the second bullet point, consider running `git rev-list -n 5` on each hash ID from the first step.  I'm not sure off-hand how to do the third step, but `git merge-base --all` might well be the ticket.)

That is, given a graph like this:

```
     C--...--H  <-- master
    /
A--B
    \
     I--...--Z  <-- br1
```

we must at least retain `B` because it's *why* `H` and `Z` are related at all.  We need not retain `C` or `I`; we just want whatever commit we *do* retain behind `H` to connect back to `B`, and whatever commit we do retain behind `Z` to connect back to `C` as well, so that we get, e.g.:

```
  D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- main
 /
B'
 \
  V'-W'-X'-Y'-Z'   <-- br1
```

Now that we know which commits to retain, traverse the entire graph again: copy commits marked "retain" and drop all the others, using the usual filter-branch / filter-repo rules.

(Along the way, we can consider updating author and/or committer name and/or email as well, if we like.)

We must make one more decision: if the input repository has both `master` *and* `main`, what should we do with the old `main`?  You can simply forbid it (make this an error) unless and until it comes up.

You'll probably want to use `git clone --mirror` to make each input to be filtered with `git filter-repo` or whatever program you come up with here, and you'll probably want to use `git push --mirror` to push the output repository *from* `git filter-repo`.

Writing the filtering code *for* `git filter-repo` (or writing your own program or coming up with some fancy script for `git filter-branch`) is going to be nontrivial.

---

#### Original answer to original question

The `git clone` command never copies *any* branches.  Instead, it copies all *branches*.

This seems self-contradictory.  How can not copying branches copy branches?  It is true, and it's also self-contradictory.  It occurs because the word *branch* doesn't have a meaning in Git.

More precisely, *branch* does not have *one* meaning.  *Branch* has *more than one meaning*.  So `git clone` copies one kind of branch, and does not copy another kind of branch.  The number of meanings for the word *branch* depends in part on how you count, and in part on what you choose to count.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) (which discusses the correct question to think about).

Now, the real problem you're having appears to be the fact that—per [this GitHub Desktop issue](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3480)—GitHub Desktop simply does not support shallow clones in the first place.  (Given that the issue was *raised* in 2017 and closed as "something we don't intend to support" in *2021*, there seems to be no urgency here, so I doubt this situation has changed.)  So while `--no-single-branch` is the correct method to defeat the default `--single-branch` action of `--depth 5`, the actual problem here is your use of `--depth 5` at all, given that you're also using GitHub Desktop.

Your two options are therefore:

1. Don't use GitHub Desktop.
2. Do a full clone.

Remember that when `git clone` makes a new clone, it:

- changes all the *other* clone's *branch* names into *remote-tracking names*, and then
- creates one *new* branch that's specific to your own repository.

You'll need to use `git switch` or `git checkout` or something to create more local branch names if you wish to have more local branch names (though your script suggests that you only really care about one branch name anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I care about all branches, but I am trying to rename any branch named "master" to "main" because all default branches in the destination repos are named "main". My entire goal here is to remove the commit history. If I was able to do that on the original repo then I would just clone without `--depth`. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah: if you want to "delete (some) history" you *must* **rewrite** history. History always goes all the way back to the beginning: the *root* commit (or one or more root commits), which are commits that have no parents. A shallow clone is one that has one or more "graft points" at which Git can see what there's some previous commit(s), but also that they are deliberately not included; such a repository has special restrictions.

Comment: I would like to explicitly remove all the commit history for the repo while maintaining all branches. That is my sole objective here but as far as I could tell there wasn't a way to do that...

Comment: You'll need to decide how much history you *do* want, because branches are just *names* that hold specific commit hash IDs. It's the *commits* that are the history, and that have relationships to each other, so if you want to have N>1 branches that are *related* they must specify final commits that in turn are related via their commit history. That means you'll want a `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` type of operation, or something klunkier but faster. Exactly what depends on what result you want.

Comment: In short, it turns out you're starting with the wrong question. 

Comment: At this point I would settle for removing all history. I'm looking for a blanket solution because there are 8 different repos to do this to.

Comment: I'm writing up a revised version of your question, which I will attempt to answer...